# Open Dialog From Other Page In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm opening a dialog component when i click the **DELETE** function button on my users list. When i click it, should show the dialog component. My problem is why i can't open it. I'm using redux to pass data to it.

Pls see this codesandbox link

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-7pib0?file=/reducers/dialog.reducer.js)

```
import { dialogConstants } from "../constants";

export const initialState = {
  title: null,
  details: null,
  isOpen: null
};

const dialogReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log(action.payload);
  switch (action.type) {
    case dialogConstants.SET_DIALOG_DETAILS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isOpen: action.payload.isOpen,
        title: action.payload.title,
        details: action.payload.details
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default dialogReducer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not importing `Dialogs` in `user.js`. So when you click button your dialog will not open. Try this:
In `user.js`:

```js
...
import DeleteDialog from "./dialog";

import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { deleteUser } from "./actions";

export default function User() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = React.useState({});
  const [open, setDialogOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleOnDelete = user => {
    setSelectedUser(user);
    setDialogOpen(true);
  };

  const handleOnAgree = () => {
    // do action to handle on agree deleting an user
    dispatch(deleteUser({ title: "Delete User", details: selectedUser }));
    setDialogOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Paper>
        <TableContainer>
          <Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>First Name</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Last Name</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Email Address</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Actions</TableCell>
                <TableCell />
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>JJJ</TableCell>
                <TableCell>BBB</TableCell>
                <TableCell>enfoie</TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  <Button variant="contained">Edit</Button>
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    onClick={() => handleOnDelete({ id: 1, name: "JJJ" })}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </Button>
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </Paper>
      <DeleteDialog
        user={selectedUser}
        open={open}
        onAgree={handleOnAgree}
        onDisagree={() => setDialogOpen(false)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In `dialog.js`:

```js
import React from "react";

import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import Slide from "@material-ui/core/Slide";

const Transition = React.forwardRef(function Transition(props, ref) {
  return <Slide direction="up" ref={ref} {...props} />;
});

const DeleteDialog = ({ user, open, onAgree, onDisagree }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        TransitionComponent={Transition}
        keepMounted
        onClose={onDisagree}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-slide-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-slide-title">
          <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
            {" "}
            User: {user.name} - {user.id}
          </span>
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button variant="contained" size="small" onClick={onDisagree}>
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button variant="contained" size="small" onClick={onAgree}>
            Confirm
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DeleteDialog;
```

[image: Edit Select with checkboxes and sub headers]

Comment: Thanks. Any idea if i click the  `onDeleteUser()` in `Dialog.js`, it will fire the `dispatch` function in the `User.js`  ?

Comment: @Robert I think your idea is the better solution, you should pass ```handleOnDisagree``` to handle ```onClose``` and ```handleOnAgree``` to handle the confirmation from ```user.js``` to ```dialog.js```. So in your ```dialog.js``` you don't need to care how ```handleOnDisagree```  and ```handleOnAgree``` work, so you can reuse ```dialog.js``` component everywhere in your project easier. Let's do it.

Comment: To show the correct answer to fire dispatch function in `User.js` when you click the `onDeleteUser()` in `Dialog.js`

Comment: @Robert I've forked your project and changed a little, I think you don't need to store ```open``` of dialog in store so I move it to ```user.js```. You can try it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-r4fd7?file=/user.js.
If it's useful, plz accept my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! There's an error on your codesandbox. Pls check it again. It says `SyntaxError
/dialog.js: Identifier 'Dialog' has already been declared (13:24)`

Comment: One last thing. I'm trying to display the user details in the dialog. How will i do it?

Comment: Thanks. So you didn't use redux in passing data then?

Comment: @Robert You just store a data field in redux store if it will be used in many components in your project. In this case, ```open``` and  ```user``` are just using in ```user.js``` so it's just stored as local data in ```user.js```.